# Select all links except the ones uses as menu in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I tried this code: `$("*:not(.menu ul li) a")`, but it ain't worked, it selected all the links. Here is the HTML used to build the menu:

```
<nav class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index,php">ראשי</a></li>
        <li><a href="index1.php">example2</a></li>
        <li class="s"><a class="has-sub">sub menu</a>
            <ul style="display: none; opacity: 1;">
                <li><a href="index2.php">hi</a></li>
                <li><a href="index3.php">hello</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="index4.php">example3</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Of course this doesn’t work – your first `li` element for example does not have the class `menu`, but it has an `a` as descendant, and so the latter matches your selector …

Comment: @CBroe So what should I do? I thought it's like css, unless I'm using `>`, it doesn't matter if there something between...

Comment: @VladGincher You could always use `$("a").not('.menu a')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, you can either use:

```
$('a:not(.menu a)')
```

or:

```
$('a').not('.menu a')
```

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ue2ZJ/)